# python bad handshake : certificate verify failed

Tags: python, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

I'm using the requests package of python and specifying the path to my certificate while making the REST call.

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=VERIFY_PATH,
                                    cookies=cookiejar)
```

"VERIFY_PATH" corresponds to the path of the certificate, which is set dynamically.

While things work fine in some environments, they fail in another environment with the following error :

```
bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')],)
```

What is **common in all the environments** is that I'm using Ubuntu14.04 LTS and requests == 2.13.0

I am not able to understand why its failing in some other enviornments with the same Ubuntu version and requests version. Is there any way I can debug this? Im using the same certificate in all cases, and my certificate is definitely valid because it works in some environments as I mentioned.

Also debug statements show that the correct path to my certificate goes in the requests call, but still the error message.

Comment: openssl version?

Comment: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3212